# next auth redirects to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true with no reason

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

next auth getting nothing in localhost. when clicking on provider, it redirects me to this page.
I'm using next13. it was working fine before.
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true
not showing any error even not logging. Previously not works fine. In vercel it works perfectly?

Thank you.

Reconfigure the project and checked the clientId and clientSecret.